# Customize the installer in IZPack

Tags: java, linux, installation, izpack, izpanel

I just want to customize the SimpleFinishPanel based on the previous panel result i.e InstallPanel.

As a part of installer am installing the "Postgres DataBase" too, and mid of the postgres installation I want to Abort the installation process. Currently even if you aborted the installation, am getting the SimpleFinishPanel with message i.e **Installatio Has Completed Successfully and An Uninstaller Program Has Created At** "**$INSTALL-PATH/Uninstall**".

Here what I am expecting is installation **GUI should indicate that the installation
was aborted and is not successful.**

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleFinishPanel.java` already contains a check for failed / successful installation:

```
if (idata.installSuccess)
{
   // We set the information
   add(LabelFactory  ...  .getString("FinishPanel.success"),
   ...
   ... translatePath("$INSTALL_PATH") + File.separator + "Uninstaller";
   ...
}
else
{
   add(LabelFactory  ...  .getString("FinishPanel.fail"),
   ...
}
```

therefore, i think you should check how the **return** from `postgres installation` is being handled - whether there's a check to differentiate between **successful / failed PostgreS return value** ?